# Append não funcionando corretamente em um Select apó requisição AJAX

Tags: jquery

Estou precisando fazer com que ao completar a requisição *AJAX* o *jquery* insira as *options* em um *select* porém ao fazer isso as options não aparecem ao clicar porém ao inspecionar mostra que estão presentes no *select*

**Script da requisição:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.get("http://localhost/infinityy/assets/php/list-categories.php", function(data){
            categories  = JSON.parse(data);
            var select = $("#category");

            $(categories).each(function(){
                 var option = $("<option>");
                 option.attr("value", this.id);
                 option.text(this.name);
                 console.log(option);

                 select.append(option);

            });
        });

 });
```

**Select:**

```
<form  action="assets/php/add-category.php" method="post">
   <div id="form" class="form-group">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Categoria <a href="#" class="add-category"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></label>
         <select id="category" name="category" class="selectpicker" data-title="Categoria" data-style="btn-default btn-block" data-menu-style="dropdown-blue" required>

     </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

**Resultado mesmo clicando não aparece as options**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Ao inspecionar o Select: **

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Visto que você está usando php, é possível fazer o que você quer com um load, seria interessante pra você? Ou tem que ser usando append?

Comment: O que seria o Load?

Comment: Uma outra função javascript para carregar as options de outra forma. Se essa for uma opção viável, eu posso fazer uma resposta com explicação de como usar essa função.

Comment: Não conheço essa função, poderia me mostrar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você adiciona opções dinamicamente ou muda o estado do select usando o `select picker`, você precisa chamar uma função que atualiza o elemento, adicione essa linha após adicionar as opções.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Mais informações: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh

Answer (score 1):

A função `load` tem uma documentação que pode ser vista [aqui](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Ela irá carregar conteúdo dentro do parâmetro passado nela. Um exemplo com o seu caso seria

Javascript:

```
$("#category").load("http://localhost/infinityy/assets/php/list-categories.php >", function () {
});
```

No php você faz a consulta que você faz do mesmo modo, mas ao invés de retornar json, retorna a variável que você quiser para uma view .php ou .phtml

HTML:

```
<?php foreach($opcoes as opcao): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $opcao['valor']?>"> <?php echo $opcao['nome']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Dessa forma, irá percorrer o array $opcoes que contem o valor e nome da sua opção e preencher o html dentro do seu select.

Comment: Tendo em vista de que é em php acho não funcionaria para o meu caso, pois estou fazendo com que o usuário possa adicionar dinamicamente as options enviando requisições ao servidor

Comment: Conhece alguma outra solução?

Comment: @LuhanSalimena é possível fazer utilizando essa função normalmente, toda vez que uma requisição for enviada ao servidor, você executa o `load`